# Turn off warning messages in scikit-learn k-nearest neighbors

Tags: python, scikit-learn

On some datasets I get this warning message in succession:

```
regression.py:130: NeighborsWarning: kneighbors: neighbor k+1 and neighbor k have the same distance: results will be dependent on data order.
neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
```

I don't think I have to worry about it (right?)... what's the best way of getting rid of the warning? Is there a flag or can I do something with my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `warn_on_equidistant=False` as argument to the Classifier. Note that in the later versions, you will no longer get this warning. You can read more [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1599).